# Eloquent SUM and GET Latest Relationship Data

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql

I have two models **User** and **Transaction**. The User model has a one-to-Many relationship with Transaction:

**I am trying to return**

1. some data from the User table
2. sum of all `amount` in the Transaction table that belongs to the user
3. transaction hash from the most recent transaction

**Expected response:**

```
  {
    "name": "User A",
    "image": "images/user-a.png",
    "last_transaction_hash": "79s8s900",
    "total_transaction_sum": "30000"
  },
  {
    "name": "User B",
    "image": "images/user-b.png",
    "transaction_hash": "a102920",
    "total_transaction_sum": "23000"
  }
```

**What I have tried:**

```
    $users = User::withCount([
        'transactions as total_transaction_sum' => function ($q) {
            return $q->select(DB::raw("SUM(amount) as amount"));
        },
    ])
        ->orderByRaw('total_transaction_sum DESC NULLS LAST')
        ->get();
```

With the above query I can return data for **(1 & 2)** but I find it hard to select the specific columns that I want to see and I still can't figure out how to return transaction hash of the latest transaction **(3)**.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Query builder` to achive this in sort line like this

```php
$users = User::select(\DB::raw('user.name, user.image, SUM(transactions.amount) as total_transaction_sum'))
    ->join('transactions', 'users.id', '=', 'transactions.user_id')
    ->orderByRaw('total_transaction_sum DESC NULLS LAST')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->map(function ($row) {
        $opt = $row;
        $opt['transaction_hash'] = optional($row->last())->id;
        return $opt;
    })->values();
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to solve 3? I want to get information from the latest transaction.

Comment: last `transaction hash` ?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the last transaction hash only

Comment: I did some tricks to get that can you check this ? or modify as per your need

Comment: I have some errors with this: 

1. The `SUM(transactions.amount)` is not showing accurate sum of amount
2. I am able to see `transactions.hash`